# How do I test this in poweshell?

Tags: xml, powershell

In a difficult spot with a retiring coworker and knowledge transfer.  My group needs to monitor a home brewed app that has a monitoring website.  I've redone most of the test into powershell except for the following.

The validation web site for the app makes a call to an xml file.  The xml file then parses the following commands and returns a green check mark.

```
<messengerData userAgent="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; 
 Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; 
 .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)">
   <intakeStatusData successText="true">     
   <testServiceStatus successText="">
      <name>Production challenger SOMESERVERNAME</name>
      <url>net.tcp://SOMESERVERNAME:SOMEPORT/challenger/</url>
    </testServiceStatus>
    <testServiceStatus successText="">
```

Comment: And what do you want to do now? Did you already try something?

Comment: I think my basic question are, what is net.tcp do? and can I replicate it in powershell?

Comment: there are no *commands* in that xml file. `net.tcp//server:port/foo/` is just a type of URI used by wcf services. The actual code doing any testing is elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq
$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load('c:\temp\test.xml')
$testServiceStatus = $xDoc.Descendants('testServiceStatus')
#Write-Output $testServiceStatus
$name = $testServiceStatus.Element('name').Value
$url = $testServiceStatus.Element('url').Value
Write-Output "name" $name
Write-Output "url" $url
```